# What's the deal with "higan"?

Tags: emulation, snes

https://byuu.org/higan/
https://byuu.org/bsnes/

1. The domain is called "byuu.org".
2. The emulator is said to be called "higan" or "bsnes".
3. The download link for "higan" goes to: https://github.com/higan-emu/higan/releases
4. That page doesn't talk about "higan" but "ares".
5. Downloading the file and running it, the application calls itself "lucia".

What is going on? Is it called higan, ares or lucia? Does the author(s) have some sort of hate against consistency to the point where it's impossible to know what the application is actually called?

I truly have no idea what's going on. I don't even have a guess. What is "lucia" and "ares"?

Comment: Please stop creating multiple accounts to post questions that character-attack emulator developers. (Stopping all of those things would be nice, but only the multiple accounts thing is a ban-worthy offence.)

Comment: I've voted to close this.  There's the possibility of a real question here (with sorting out the names) but asking us to speculate on the author's psychology is going a bit too far.

Answer (score 4):

The history is somewhat complex, but explained in [the higan wiki](https://github.com/higan-emu/higan/wiki/Component-map), [the higan site](https://byuu.org/higan/) and [the ares site](https://byuu.org/ares/).

bsnes was originally a SNES emulator, with the goal of being as accurate as possible. Its author went by the nick “byuu”. After a while, other emulation targets were added to bsnes, so its name was deemed inaccurate, and byuu renamed it to higan. In March 2020 byuu retired from the project, handing it to the community; but then during the pandemic, byuu started developing it again, as a fork named ares.

To make things a bit more complex, byuu was also the name of a UI for higan, written by the original author, who started using the nick “Near”. This UI is now called lucia.

So ares is the emulator, and lucia is a UI for it.